Black screen on boot: can I use 24.04 without permanent "nomodeset"
I have a HP 17-cp1147ng notebook from the end of 2022.
I've just installed Kubuntu 24.04 on it.
I get a black screen after the HP logo on starting up (first time).
I followed this advice (section "Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time"): My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?
[An important edit: with (U)EFI-installed systems press the ESC key upon starting, not the SHIFT or RIGHT SHIFT as mentioned in this advice; SHIFT is for old BIOS installations).
It worked (once). So I followed the advice specified there, and went to:
How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?
(don't forget to update Grub after editing the file, folks; I forgot and spent some time looking for the problem on rebooting).
The notebook is going to go to someone else. The fix might get undone, leaving just a black screen.
Can I, for instance, update the graphics driver (AMD Radeon Graphics)?
Most help pages on the "nomodeset" problem seemed to be very old (2018 etc.) or were some complex dual boot setup.
I installed only Kubuntu on the entire hard disc, with no bells and whistles. The graphics GPU must also be at least 1.5 years old (sorry, I specified "end of 2023" at first; I've corrected that to "end of 2022", 1.5 years ago).
amdgpu is installed, I checked that.
And, by the way, the notebook worked "out of the box" with the same Kubuntu 22.04 setup. No black screen there. Seems to be a kind of regression.
Any absolutely permanent solution?
Additional hardware information:
lspci -v | less:
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo (rev c2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
DeviceName: AMD Radeon Integrated Graphics
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Barcelo
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255, IOMMU group 11
Memory at fce0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at fcf0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
I/O ports at 1000 [disabled] [size=256]
Memory at d0400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
Capabilities: 
Kernel modules: amdgpu
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version:
F.03

The website below says AMD "Barcelo" works since Kernel 5.13. That would fit, because in 22.04 there was no problem. Still, does anyone have a proper fix, like a closed-source driver? Any experience? https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:1002-15e7-17aa-50b1&page=2#status

I have filed a bug report at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/2063877

A kernel downgrade seems to work. But I don't really want to do that; see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2063983

I found a workaround myself. (See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2064815). If you have the same problem, do this:

Edit /etc/default/grub: the line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=". Delete the words "quiet splash" (leave the quotation marks '').
Run sudo update-grub


Thank your:)
It's work for me. xubuntu 24.04, amd 7940hs, UM790 Pro miniPC. Edit /etc/default/grub: the line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=". Delete the words "quiet splash" (leave the quotation marks ''). - Run sudo update-grub
