24.04 Black Screen with AMD
Identical hardware works perfect with 23.10 so its 24.04 related.
Same issue with Kubuntu so its not KDE or Gnome specific
Ryzen 5950x, AMD W4100 (GCN1,CapeVerde) GPU, EFI booting
I've managed to install it once but every boot I get black screen and even if I use recovery boot and select normal, I get a picture but then no audio (the HDMI audio portion of my GPU shows as Inactive). It's like 24.04 has no AMD GPU support (or feels like that) as 23.10 works fine.
I'm back on 23.10 but would like to be able to use 24.04

Might this help? https://askubuntu.com/q/1511762/1784833
